# Change Image color

Tags: c#, gdi+, gdi

I am working on a project where in the shopping cart a user can select a certain color for an item.

The problem is there are tons of color choices available but the manufacturer has only provided with one product image. Now I need to come up with a way to change the color of this product based on user selection. This is pretty similar to going on car manufacturers website ... when you click on a color the image is updated with that color.

Any ideas how to go about accomplishing this?

Note: My initial thought was to use photoshop to comeup with a tranparent image which only has shadow details of the produc (and the surrounding areas are solid/opaque) and then programatically merge this transparent image with another image with the selected color. Theoratically it can be done ... I am just wanting to know if someone has already done this before and/or if there is a better way ... like perhaps using photoshop filters etc :)

Answer (score 3):

The one you are thinking is probably best option to do. And instead of merging the image on server side (assuming it is Asp.net code) use javascript to place the image over main image. best way is to load all colored image and main image and place colored image over main impage. Use PNG format for better transparent images.

You dont have to use server  resource everytime each user change the color when you know you have fixed number of  color options.

Answer (score 1):

If the part that needs to be colored is unique in the original in terms of hue (and you could make it unique by changing it in the source image through Photoshop or something), this should do the trick. It works by locking an input bitmap (so each pixel can be manipulated) and then converting each pixel to HSB so that hue (the "color") of the pixel can be adjusted *if* it falls within a certain range of hues. This will have a nice effect because gradients such as shadow and slight variances will also be colorized correctly.

Colorizing code:

```
Bitmap bmp = ...
byte minHue = 0;
byte maxHue = 10;
byte newHue = 128;
```

...

```
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
int bytes = bmpData.Stride * bmpData.Height;
byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
for (int c = 0; c < rgbValues.Length; c += 4)
{
    HSBColor hsb = new HSBColor(Color.FromArgb(
        rgbValues[c + 3], rgbValues[c + 2],
        rgbValues[c + 1], rgbValues[c]));
if(hsb.H > minHue && hsb.H < maxHue)
    {
        hsb.H = Convert.ToByte(newHue);
    }
    Color color = hsb.ToRGB();
    rgbValues[c] = color.B;
    rgbValues[c + 1] = color.G;
    rgbValues[c + 2] = color.R;
    rgbValues[c + 3] = color.A;
}
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes);
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

HSBColor.cs (from ZedGraph):

```
/// <summary>
/// Hue-Saturation-Brightness Color class to store a color value, and to manage conversions
/// to and from RGB colors in the <see cref="Color" /> struct.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This class is based on code from http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/ by Eugene Vishnevsky.
/// This struct stores the hue, saturation, brightness, and alpha values internally as
/// <see cref="byte" /> values from 0 to 255.  The hue represents a fraction of the 360 degrees
/// of color space available. The saturation is the color intensity, where 0 represents gray scale
/// and 255 is the most colored.  For the brightness, 0 represents black and 255
/// represents white.
/// </remarks>
[Serializable]
public struct HSBColor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The color hue value, ranging from 0 to 255.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This property is actually a rescaling of the 360 degrees on the color wheel to 255
    /// possible values.  Therefore, every 42.5 units is a new sector, with the following
    /// convention:  red=0, yellow=42.5, green=85, cyan=127.5, blue=170, magenta=212.5
    /// </remarks>
    public byte H;
    /// <summary>
    /// The color saturation (intensity) value, ranging from 0 (gray scale) to 255 (most colored).
    /// </summary>
    public byte S;
    /// <summary>
    /// The brightness value, ranging from 0 (black) to 255 (white).
    /// </summary>
    public byte B;
    /// <summary>
    /// The alpha value (opacity), ranging from 0 (transparent) to 255 (opaque).
    /// </summary>
    public byte A;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor to load an <see cref="HSBColor" /> struct from hue, saturation and
    /// brightness values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="h">The color hue value, ranging from 0 to 255</param>
    /// <param name="s">The color saturation (intensity) value, ranging from 0 (gray scale)
    /// to 255 (most colored)</param>
    /// <param name="b">The brightness value, ranging from 0 (black) to 255 (white)</param>
    public HSBColor(int h, int s, int b)
    {
        this.H = (byte)h;
        this.S = (byte)s;
        this.B = (byte)b;
        this.A = 255;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor to load an <see cref="HSBColor" /> struct from hue, saturation,
    /// brightness, and alpha values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="h">The color hue value, ranging from 0 to 255</param>
    /// <param name="s">The color saturation (intensity) value, ranging from 0 (gray scale)
    /// to 255 (most colored)</param>
    /// <param name="b">The brightness value, ranging from 0 (black) to 255 (white)</param>
    /// <param name="a">The alpha value (opacity), ranging from 0 (transparent) to
    /// 255 (opaque)</param>
    public HSBColor(int a, int h, int s, int b)
        : this(h, s, b)
    {
        this.A = (byte)a;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor to load an <see cref="HSBColor" /> struct from a system
    /// <see cref="Color" /> struct.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="color">An rgb <see cref="Color" /> struct containing the equivalent
    /// color you want to generate</param>
    public HSBColor(Color color)
    {
        this = FromRGB(color);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Implicit conversion operator to convert directly from an <see cref="HSBColor" /> to
    /// a <see cref="Color" /> struct.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hsbColor">The <see cref="HSBColor" /> struct to be converted</param>
    /// <returns>An equivalent <see cref="Color" /> struct that can be used in the GDI+
    /// graphics library</returns>
    public static implicit operator Color(HSBColor hsbColor)
    {
        return ToRGB(hsbColor);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert an <see cref="HSBColor" /> value to an equivalent <see cref="Color" /> value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method is based on code from http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/ by Eugene Vishnevsky.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="hsbColor">The <see cref="HSBColor" /> struct to be converted</param>
    /// <returns>An equivalent <see cref="Color" /> struct, compatible with the GDI+ library</returns>
    public static Color ToRGB(HSBColor hsbColor)
    {
        Color rgbColor = Color.Black;

        // Determine which sector of the color wheel contains this hue
        // hsbColor.H ranges from 0 to 255, and there are 6 sectors, so 42.5 per sector
        int sector = (int)Math.Floor((double)hsbColor.H / 42.5);
        // Calculate where the hue lies within the sector for interpolation purpose
        double fraction = (double)hsbColor.H / 42.5 - (double)sector;

        double sFrac = (double)hsbColor.S / 255.0;
        byte p = (byte)(((double)hsbColor.B * (1.0 - sFrac)) + 0.5);
        byte q = (byte)(((double)hsbColor.B * (1.0 - sFrac * fraction)) + 0.5);
        byte t = (byte)(((double)hsbColor.B * (1.0 - sFrac * (1.0 - fraction))) + 0.5);


        switch (sector)
        {
            case 0:         // red - yellow
                rgbColor = Color.FromArgb(hsbColor.A, hsbColor.B, t, p);
                break;
            case 1:         // yellow - green
                rgbColor = Color.FromArgb(hsbColor.A, q, hsbColor.B, p);
                break;
            case 2:         // green - cyan
                rgbColor = Color.FromArgb(hsbColor.A, p, hsbColor.B, t);
                break;
            case 3:         // cyan - blue
                rgbColor = Color.FromArgb(hsbColor.A, p, q, hsbColor.B);
                break;
            case 4:         // blue - magenta
                rgbColor = Color.FromArgb(hsbColor.A, t, p, hsbColor.B);
                break;
            case 5:
            default:        // magenta - red
                rgbColor = Color.FromArgb(hsbColor.A, hsbColor.B, p, q);
                break;
        }

        return rgbColor;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert this <see cref="HSBColor" /> value to an equivalent <see cref="Color" /> value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method is based on code from http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/ by Eugene Vishnevsky.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <returns>An equivalent <see cref="Color" /> struct, compatible with the GDI+ library</returns>
    public Color ToRGB()
    {
        return ToRGB(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a <see cref="Color" /> value to an equivalent <see cref="HSBColor" /> value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method is based on code from http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/ by Eugene Vishnevsky.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <returns>An equivalent <see cref="HSBColor" /> struct</returns>
    public HSBColor FromRGB()
    {
        return FromRGB(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a <see cref="Color" /> value to an equivalent <see cref="HSBColor" /> value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method is based on code from http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ncs/color/ by Eugene Vishnevsky.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="rgbColor">The <see cref="Color" /> struct to be converted</param>
    /// <returns>An equivalent <see cref="HSBColor" /> struct</returns>
    public static HSBColor FromRGB(Color rgbColor)
    {
        double r = (double)rgbColor.R / 255.0;
        double g = (double)rgbColor.G / 255.0;
        double b = (double)rgbColor.B / 255.0;

        double min = Math.Min(Math.Min(r, g), b);
        double max = Math.Max(Math.Max(r, g), b);

        HSBColor hsbColor = new HSBColor(rgbColor.A, 0, 0, 0);

        hsbColor.B = (byte)(max * 255.0 + 0.5);

        double delta = max - min;

        if (max != 0.0)
        {
            hsbColor.S = (byte)(delta / max * 255.0 + 0.5);
        }
        else
        {
            hsbColor.S = 0;
            hsbColor.H = 0;
            return hsbColor;
        }

        double h;
        if (r == max)
            h = (g - b) / delta;        // between yellow & magenta
        else if (g == max)
            h = 2 + (b - r) / delta;    // between cyan & yellow
        else
            h = 4 + (r - g) / delta;    // between magenta & cyan

        hsbColor.H = (byte)(h * 42.5);
        if (hsbColor.H < 0)
            hsbColor.H += 255;

        return hsbColor;
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please explain how I get the values for minHue, maxHue and newHue?

Thanks btw!!

Comment: Like for instance i have a black and white image and I want black color to be changed ... how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Sorry - didn't see this comment until just now. `minHue` and `maxHue` are ranges to change and `newHue` is the target. If the hue of a given pixel falls between `minHue` and `maxHue`, it will be changed to the `newHue` hue. Hue is a measure of the "color" of a pixel - red-like colors have one hue while green-like colors have a different one. Here's a tool that should help play with colors and look at their values in different color spaces: http://www.colourlovers.com/copaso/ColorPaletteSoftware

Comment: Shades of grey (including black and white) are all hue-neutral and therefore this approach wouldn't work as-written for that situation. However, you could adjust the `if(hsb.H > minHue && hsb.H < maxHue)` line to compare saturation (the amount of color) or brightness (the closeness to black or white) instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Scene7](http://www.scene7.com/) does this for you but it's pretty costly.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the colours in one image to a new set of colours fairly easily with an array of `ColourMap[]` - the problem is the source colours and the destination colours.

I use a code like this with a map of a single colour (black) with various alpha levels of transparency (though you could use a greyscale image in the same way), then map every colour in the scale to the new scale:

```
// Get the source file and create a result bitmap of the same size
using (var source = Image.FromFile("old colour image.png", false))
using (var result = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height))
{
    // Build a colour map of old to new colour
    ColorMap[] colorMap = BuildArrayOfOldAndNewColours();

    // Build image attributes with the map
    var attr = new ImageAttributes();
    attr.SetRemapTable(colorMap);

    // Draw a rectangle the same size as the image
    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height);

    // Draw the old image into the new one with one colour mapped to the other
    var g = Graphics.FromImage(result);
    g.DrawImage(source, rect, 0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attr);

    result.Save("new colour image.png");
}
```

This works great with simple icons, but you may need quite a complicated map to deal with anything photo-quality.